# Windows Forms sizes not matching

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I've got some very strict requirements on windows form sizes for elements and I've been having some trouble actually matching that up, I figured out the problem but I don't understand why I'm getting it. I have a picture box that needs to be a specific size, when I set it to that size in the properties panel of visual studio, it doesn't actually take that size, but a value smaller than that. It was throwing off my development. I can rectify it by manually setting the size value in the form code, however I'd like to know why the properties tab doesn't automatically do it correctly. I've just got it outputting the precise size value to a message box.

[image: Actual size]

[image: Properties window]

Answer (score 9):

I have noticed the exact same behaviour in my project today. The form and all objects on it hat a certain size, but when run, the size was all different.

After checking the InitializeComponents() I found this line

```
this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
```

so I checked the according property, and I changed it to "None".
Have never actually witnessed this behaviour before, but this did the trick for me. Now the Forms and everything else has the specified size.

Answer (score 1):

The **Size** is actually size of whole window including the borders of windows form. You can see that the inner portion has exactly 18 pixels less for both width and height. You might calculate the desired width and height to assign to the form. Like if you want 100 x 100 pixel inner window size, you can assign 118 x 118 pixel for the size.

Comment: That has to be done for everything inside the form? So this is just with a picturebox element atm, though the form is out as well but I didn't check by how much.

Comment: It does depend on widows style and OS? Doesn't it?

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm pretty new at windows form development.

Comment: You could try setting the size of the client area (client size) instead of the form's size. Then you don't have to take border dimensions into account.

Answer (score 1):

Any of the following properties of PictureBox could have caused it:

- Anchor
- Dock
- Margin
- MinimumSize
- MaximumSize
- SizeMode

Also need to check the direct parent (container) of your `PictureBox`. Is it directly put in the Form, or inside another container like `GroupBox` or `Panel`? If latter is the case, you should check properties of the parent object too.

Comment: The picture box is put directly on the form and I've not changed any of the other properties mentioned beyond their default.

Comment: @Thallazar: Then I do not see any reason for this behavior. Do one thing. Check your `InitializeComponent()` code. This may be a side-effect of some other control, although I highly doubt that. But seeing that it works good when you size it manually in the constructor, that is your only hope AFAIK.

Answer (score -1):

Size of you pictureBox is determined according to size of Form. That is why you picturebox does not fit size you defined.

Comment: The size of the form is giving the exact same problem though. It's value is different to what is inputted on properties.